# In Django, how do I make uniques on 3 fields?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-models

```
class ExternalFriends(models.Model):
    external_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    external_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, db_index=T
rue)
```

So let's say I want all 3 fields to be "unique_together".  How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Meta option [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#unique-together).  This takes a tuple (or tuples) describing sets of columns that should be considered unique together.

The model would look like this:

```
class ExternalFriends(models.Model):
    # columns

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('external_user', 'name', 'external_account_id'),
```

Comment: But how can I do THREE items? I know how to do two.

Comment: Put three field names in the tuple.

Comment: I thought tuples were 2 things only.

Comment: Tuples are variable-length, immutable sequences. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences