# How can i create unique together based on a field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my code:

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='addresses',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    long = models.FloatField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['lat', 'long'], name='lat_long_unique')
```

I want the field lat long unique together but just with the same customer, how can I achieve that?

I tried :

```py
fields=['customer', 'lat', 'long']
```

And didn't validate at all

Edit, data example :
let's say I already have the:

```
cust1 lat1 long1
cust2 lat2 long2
```

with `UniqueConstraint(fields=['lat', 'long']` if I insert `cust3 lat1 long1` its returns the below error:

```
address with lat long already exist
```

with

```py
unique_together('customer', 'lat', 'long')
```

or

```py
unique_together(('customer', 'lat',), ('customer','long',))
```

if I insert `cust1 lat1 long1` its successful to add

Edit:

When adding a customer in the constraint field and after migrating.I got the following error when enter the same value

```
IntegrityError at /customers/addresses/add/

duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customer_lat_long_unique"
DETAIL: Key(lat, long, customer_id)=(-6.241181999999999, 106.814273, 2) already exists.
```

But I didn't get the same debug-page error when only lat and long in constraint field. I just handle it in the template with `{{form.non_field_errors}}` returning:

```
Addresses with this lat long already exist.
```

Comment: have you tried with the unique_together property for 3 fields in meta? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785065/11225821

Comment: @LinhNguyen tried `unique_together('customer', 'lat', 'long')`, its not validating

Comment: can you post some data example where it not working to the question?

Comment: did you create a migration and migrate it? because constraints will need a migration to apply new constraints

Comment: @LinhNguyen already migrate it and it work, but when i tried to insert the same input now it throws IntegrityError, showing the debug page. When my constraint only lat and long it didnt go to the debug page, it just showing an error in template form.errors. Any idea?

Comment: can you post the error to the question? we can't really know what error it's returning

Comment: @LinhNguyen edited with the errors